# Sveltekit - prevent form error 500 redirect

Tags: sveltekit

In form action I throw error 500, and handle it in **enhance** function.
BUT it still redirects to error page after it.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a form action, instead of throwing an error you can use Sveltekit's fail function to return an error to the frontend:

```
import { fail } from '@sveltejs/kit';


// inside your form action method
if (!condition) {
    return fail(500, { randomAttribute: 123 });
}
```

By doing so, you can easily handle the error in the `use:enhance` directive:

```
<form method="POST" use:enhance={() => {
    return async ({ result }) => {
        if (result.type === 'failure') {
            // result.status contains the error code
            // result.data contains the data object you passed in the fail function
        }
    };
}}>

</form>
```

Comment: yes that's the way i solved. very clear answer. thank you.